# Using tensorflow.contrib with cv_bridge causes tcmalloc error

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, ros

The following script

```
import tensorflow.contrib
import cv_bridge

import rospy
rospy.init_node('node')
```

throws the following error:

```
/usr/bin/python2.7    
/home/ethan/.PyCharmCE2016.3/config/scratches/scratch_4.py
src/tcmalloc.cc:277] Attempt to free invalid pointer 0xa2e78616d5f7475
```

Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)

Operating System:

```
❯ uname -a 
Linux dos 3.13.0-76-generic #120-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 18 15:59:10 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/
```

I've tried reinstalling cv_bridge and tensorflow. No luck.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the solution was to switch the order of imports:

```
import cv_bridge
import tensorflow.contrib

import rospy
rospy.init_node('node')
```

This is a bug and I've posted issues on the tensorflow and opencv githubs.

**EDIT:**
I found this unfortunate line in my `.zshrc`:

```
export LD_PRELOAD="/usr/lib/libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4"
```

Not sure why I added that. Commenting it out solved the problem. While not a bug, I think it would helpful to have some kind of more informative error message.

This is [the issue on the Tensorflow Github page](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8146) and this is [the one on the OpenCV page](https://github.com/ros-perception/vision_opencv/issues/161).

Comment: Great that you figured it out. It would be good if you could link the github issues here. Then others with the same problem can more easily find them to see how the status is.